# Зависает интерфейс при выполнение цикла во втором потоке в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread, movetothread

Запускаю функцию `test_func()` во втором потоке, в котором есть цикл, из основного класса `App`, и интерфейс виснет.

Если, к примеру, перенести цикл из `test_func()` в `run()`, то интерфейс не зависает. 
Разница между этими функциями в том, что `test_func()` вызывается `emit`'ом из основного класса `App`, а `run()` самовоспроизводится при старте класса `ThreadForFunc`.

Надеюсь, моя проблема ясна.

**Код:**

*Примечание: первые три класса можете пропустить, в них находятся окна. Сама проблема кроется в последних двух классах - `ThreadForFunc` и `App`*

```
import sys
#import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer, Qt


class Ui_MainWindow(object):                              # основное окно
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(224, 240, 291, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 351, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПЕРВОЕ ОКНО"))



class Ui_Form(object):                            # окно прогресса
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(431, 262)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: #21222D;")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 190, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"border-radius: 15px;\n"
"color: #21222D;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 351, 2))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.progressBar.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.progressBar.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.progressBar.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.progressBar.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.progressBar.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{\n"
"    background-color: #555661;\n"
"    color: #16171E;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    max-height: 2.45px;\n"
"    min-height: 2.45px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 #FFC468, stop:1 #F27F7D);\n"
"}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "ЗАКРЫТЬ"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "ПОДОЖДИТE"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Идет загрузка"))


class Progress_UI(QWidget):             # класс для инициализации окна прогресса
    def __init__(self):
        super(Progress_UI, self).__init__()
        self.setup_progress()

    def setup_progress(self):
        self.progress_ui = Ui_Form()
        self.progress_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.progress_ui.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint |    
        QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.progress_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)


class ThreadForFunc(QThread):        
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print('Start run')


    def test_func(self):               # собственно, функция, которая должна работать. Пока что после её запуска интерфейс виснет
        print('Работает!')
        self.num = 0
        while True:
            print(f'{self.num}')
            self.msleep(1000)
            self.num += 1
    

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()                         # my_signal                 

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # запускаем нужную функцию по нажатию на кнопку
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ais_start) 
        
        self.thread = ThreadForFunc()                               
        self.my_signal.connect(self.thread.test_func)       # my_signal.connect()


    def show_progress_ui(self):
        self.progress_ui = Progress_UI()
        self.progress_ui.show()           


    def ais_start(self):
        self.show_progress_ui()
        self.thread.start()
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.my_signal.emit)         # my_signal.emit()    
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отдельном потоке запускается функция `run` из класса `ThreadForFunc`, а `test_func` запускается из главного потока, в котором обрабатываются события UI. Поэтому и зависает UI, пока функция не вернется.

Вероятно, вы хотите запустить из `ais_start` новый поток, в котором будет вызываться `test_func`. Тогда нужно делать так:

```
class ThreadForFunc(QThread):        
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print('Start run')
        self.test_func()

    def test_func(self):
        print('Работает!')
        self.num = 0
        while True:
            print(f'{self.num}')
            self.msleep(1000)
            self.num += 1
    

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        ... тут все как раньше
        
        self.thread = ThreadForFunc()                               
        self.my_signal.connect(self.thread.start)

    ... все так же

    def ais_start(self):
        self.show_progress_ui()
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.my_signal.emit)
```

Т.е. `test_func` должна вызываться напрямую из `run`, а сигнал должен запускать поток используя `start`.

Comment: Но тогда мне нужно будет для каждого случая, где нужен второй поток, создавать индивидуальный класс с потоком. Так делать стоит разве?

Comment: Создавать разные классы вовсе необязательно. Возможно это и имеет смысл, но трудно ответить определенно, так как неизвестно, что должны делать эти потоки в этих разных случаях. В вопросе вы описываете одну проблему, и ответ о ней.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял и вам надо выполнить какую-то функцию в дополнительном потоке, тогда вам нужен другой подход.

> void QObject::**moveToThread(QThread *targetThread)**
>
> Изменяет привязку потока для этого объекта и его дочерних элементов. Объект нельзя переместить, если у него есть родитель. Обработка событий продолжится в targetThread.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):                        # основное окно
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(224, 240, 291, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 351, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ПЕРВОЕ ОКНО"))



class Ui_Form(object):                            # окно прогресса
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(431, 262)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: #21222D;")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 190, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;\n"
"border: 2px solid white;\n"
"border-radius: 15px;\n"
"color: #21222D;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 351, 2))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.progressBar.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.progressBar.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.progressBar.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.progressBar.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.progressBar.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{\n"
"    background-color: #555661;\n"
"    color: #16171E;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    max-height: 2.45px;\n"
"    min-height: 2.45px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QProgressBar::chunk{\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 #FFC468, stop:1 #F27F7D);\n"
"}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Golos Text")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "ЗАКРЫТЬ"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "ПОДОЖДИТE"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Идет загрузка"))


class Progress_UI(QWidget):             # класс для инициализации окна прогресса
    def __init__(self):
        super(Progress_UI, self).__init__()
        self.setup_progress()

    def setup_progress(self):
        self.progress_ui = Ui_Form()
        self.progress_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.progress_ui.progressBar.setRange(0, 0)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint |    
        QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.progress_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)


class Worker(QObject):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)                   
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    
    def run(self):
        print('Работает! thread id ->', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        self.num = 0
        for i in range(1, 101):
            self.valueChanged.emit(self.num)
            QThread.msleep(100)
            self.num += 1
        self.finished.emit()
        

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # запускаем нужную функцию по нажатию на кнопку
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ais_start) 
        
        # Current thread id
        print('main id = ', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        # Start thread update progress bar value
        self._thread = QThread(self)
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)        # Move to thread to execute
        
        self._worker.finished.connect(self.finished_worker)
        self._worker.valueChanged.connect(self.set_value)

    def finished_worker(self):
        print(f'finished_worker !!!')
        self.progress_ui.hide()
    
    def set_value(self, value):
        print(f'value:{value}')

    def show_progress_ui(self):
        self.progress_ui = Progress_UI()
        self.progress_ui.show()           

    def ais_start(self):
        self.show_progress_ui()
  
        print('main id -> ', int(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        self._thread.start()                                   # Start thread
        QTimer.singleShot(1, self._worker.run)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я хочу поместить в поток несколько функций, и в определенном случаи использовать один из них, то и этот пример не решает мою проблему, верно? Тогда мне остаётся для каждого отдельного случая, где мне необходим второй поток, создавать новый класс с потоком. Правильно ли так делать?

Comment: @GalaevIsmail не совсем понимаю о чем вы говорите. Вам надо лучше объяснить что вы хотите сделать, привести пример со всеми функциями, о которых вы говорите и тогда уже говорить что вам подходит или нет.

Comment: Ладно, не суть. Буду создавать потоки как в примере Романа, и для каждого случая создам отдельные классы с потоком. Спасибо большое за помощь, Вы всегда выручаете!